# jQuery HTML problem

Tags: jquery

I wrote this:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("div.productInfo").wrap("<div id='productDetails'></div>");
    </script>
</head>

<body>
     <div class="productInfo">Whatever.</div>
</body>
```

And it didn't work?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your element hasn't been rendered when your script runs... try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.productInfo").wrap("<div id='productDetails' />");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It worked but some of my images removed I have no clue why? Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that your "productDetails" div should also have a "productInfo" class so that it inherits the same styles and doesn't affect your layout

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've left out document.ready:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.productInfo").wrap("<div id='productDetails' />");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It worked but some of my images removed I have no clue why? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Place the SCRIPT elements at the bottom of the page and use a [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>A valid page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="productInfo">Whatever.</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('div.productInfo').wrap('<div id="productDetails"></div>');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked but some of my images removed I have no clue why? Thanks